# Google place API's give wrong result in iOS App

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using goole place API for finding near by places, but always it gives me wrong value.

Here is my framed link - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.848048,77.654625&radius=10000&types=**courier_services**&sensor=true&key=[API_KEY].

Another way of framing the URL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=42.848048,34.654625&radius=10000&types=**courier_services**&sensor=true&key=[API_KEY].

Here i am searching for courier services around my places, but i get some irrelevant results. It gives me few hotel details in the response. Above both url's results same response.

Does anybody has any idea or faced the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the list of [supported place-types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=en#table1) , **`courier_services`** currently is not a supported type.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I will try that. Also Google Place API doc's say's we can look for place in 50,000 meter radius, but when i pass 50,000 i could see only items in between 20,000 meter. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use the parameter `types`. Because it is [Deprecated](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#deprecation):

> Notice: The implementation for `types` in text search requests is
>   changing. The `types` parameter is deprecated as of February 16, 2016,
>   replaced by a new `type` parameter which only supports one type per
>   search request.

So use type instead of types.

Also, I tried your request, and your correct I'm getting some Hotel names. But, after checking the supported `type` for the Places API. I cannot find the word **courier_services**. Just check this [documentaion](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1) to know what is the supportive type in the Places API.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I will try that. Also Google Place API doc's say's we can look for place in 50,000 meter radius, but when i pass 50,000 i could see only items in between 20,000 meter. Any idea?